# Can i create OwinMiddleware per request instead creating a global object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, owin

I'm working on the webapi project & now we are migrating to Owin/Katana hosting. I have few doubts regarding.

Quest ) Can i create OwinMiddleware per request instead creating a global object?

I'm able to create owinMiddleware but not able to create them per request. I wanted to create them per request so that i can insert a new object in owinMiddleware as dependency. I'm already using unity in webapi so wanted some solution aligned with unity.

I found few links :-

http://alexmg.com/owin-support-for-the-web-api-2-and-mvc-5-integrations-in-autofac/

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/owin-dependencies--an-ioc-container-adapter-into-owin-pipeline

but not able to adjust a new IoC with old unity. Can anybody suggest any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way by which we could achive this :-

```
        app.Use((IOwinContext context, Func<Task> next) =>
        {
            ILogger logger = {Resolve dependency using Unity};
            CustomOwinMiddleware middleware = new CustomOwinMiddleware(context,next, logger);
            return middleware.Invoke();
        });
```

By this way I'm able to generate my middle ware per request. Is it the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a single middleware instance for all requests that can be injected with unity if you so choose. I would then create a lifetimemanager within the invoke method of that middleware and inject whatever functions you want as delegates rather than calling invoke on another middleware. If you need the OwinContext in those functions you can just pass them as parameters.

See this blog post here for more information:
http://codetoast.org/orchard/blog/using-unity-owin-and-web-api-to-organize-log-entries-by-request